# Sharepoint Jquery attr returning undefined for populated column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a script running in a SharePoint list that updates the value of the URL of a Hyperlink or Image column depending on a field called TD Status, I then need to read this updated field again for verification purposes. For now i'm testing to see if the updates go through with a test field called CurrentStageImg, the field updates fine when I call UpdateListItems, but after its value is set and the script runs again, the call $(this).attr("ows_CurrentStageImg"); keeps returning 'undefined' on a test alert even though I can clearly see the column is populated on the SharePoint list. I am extremely frustrated by now and help would be much appreciated. My code below:

```
$().SPServices({
   operation: "GetListItems",
   async: false,
   listName: "Software Request",
   CAMLQuery: query,
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

      var tdStatus = $(this).attr("ows_TD_x0020_Status0");
      var currItemImg = $(this).attr("ows_CurrentStageImg");
      var itemId = $(this).attr("ows_ID");

      alert(itemId + " " + currItemImg);
```

in the code above, the value of currItemImg should be the same as tdStatus since that is what im using for test purposes, as I said, the field CurrentStageImg is populated on the list and that is 
the field's internal name so I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.... here's the update call code:
(both TD Status and CurrentStageImg are drop downs with the same values... not sure if that is a factor...

```
updateListItem(itemId,'CurrentStageImg', tdStatus);

function updateListItem(updateItemId, field2, newValue2) {

var list = "Software Request";
        //perform actual update
    $().SPServices({
        operation:"UpdateListItems",
        listName: list,
        ID: updateItemId,
        valuepairs: [[field2, newValue2]]
    });
```

}

Comment: If it's undefined it's because it's undefined, either the name of the attribute is wrong, or it could be that something else is 'defining it' after this `each` statement is running? I can't think of any other possibility I'm afraid.

Comment: @deeMacI thought the name was wrong at first, but I keep checking and im using the name as shown in the internal URL name... what else could be defining it? this script runs everytime the page loads...

Comment: Check `$(this)` on both case, I suspect the error is here.

Comment: i'm sorry, what do you mean by checking '$(this)'? I'm afraid I don't understand...